# Rails gem acts_as_list: How to handle reordering of list items when a list item is destroyed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, acts-as-list

I'm using [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) v0.9.17 this way:

```
class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_list scope: [:column1_id, :column2_id], :add_new_at => :bottom
end
```

When a new (scoped) `@list_item` is created, say the one where `column1_id` is `1`, `column2_id` is `11` and `column3_id` is `37`, the database looks as follows, as expected:

```
id  | position | column1_id | column2_id | column3_id
--- | -------- | ---------- | ---------- | ----------
750 | 1        | 1          | 11         | 89
751 | 2        | 1          | 11         | 56
752 | 3        | 1          | 11         | 105
753 | 4        | 1          | 11         | 25
754 | 5        | 1          | 11         | 37
```

However, when a `@list_item` is destroyed, say the one where `column1_id` is `1`, `column2_id` is `11` and `column3_id` is `56` (record id `751`), then the database looks as follows:

```
id  | position | column1_id | column2_id | column3_id
--- | -------- | ---------- | ---------- | ----------
750 | 1        | 1          | 11         | 89
752 | 3        | 1          | 11         | 105
753 | 4        | 1          | 11         | 25
754 | 5        | 1          | 11         | 37
```

That means there is a gap for `position` `2`.

How to prevent or adjust the gap? That is, how to handle reordering of list items when a list item is destroyed?

---

Note: I know there are [methods that change position and reorder list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list#methods-that-change-position-and-reorder-list) but I don't know whether
and how to use them to solve the issue (maybe using someway [`remove_from_list`](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/blob/master/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb#L120)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say you need to use the method you provided, and you can either do it in your controller or the model itself. If you're the kind of guy who likes callbacks, then:

```
class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_list scope: [:column1_id, :column2_id], :add_new_at => :bottom
  before_destroy { |record| record.remove_from_list }

  ....
end
```

Some people don't like handling logic like that as a callback, so you can also add it straight into your controller:

```
class ListItemsController < Wherever
  ....
  ....

  def destroy
    @list_item.remove_from_list
    @list_item.delete

    ....
  end
end
```

Personally I'd add it into the model but they both do the same thing.

If you need to try and fix a list that has a missing record in it, say you have LineItems with an ID and position of 0-4 and 6-9, missing position 5. You can make a dirtyish fix in console with:

```
LineItem.where('position >= ?', 5).each { |line_item| line_item.update_attributes(position: line_item.position - 1) }
```

This will find all LineItems with a position over 4, and decrement each of them by one, leaving you with a correctly ordered list from 0-8.

Comment: The destroy callback is added for you: https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/blob/0440822674685bc29ca119e25f57ae5e9c3724c9/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/callback_definer.rb#L9 so no need to do it manually. Per https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/issues/347 I think the OP has misconfigured something but we need more information.

Comment: I was wrong in showing column data and I updated the question. At this time I am solving the issue by using the `before_destroy { |record| record.remove_from_list }` callback inside the model but, since ActsAsList has one itself as @Brendon Muir pointed out, probably I should use it. Maybe I misconfigured something. Let me know if you need further info.

Comment: UPDATE - I (subtly) misconfigured the `:scope` option. Now all works without the use of the `before_destroy` callback. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update as I was about to spend some more time on this :)

Comment: @Backo, you should create an answer that shows your solution to the problem and accept that as the answer if this answer isn't the correct solution.

Comment: @BrendonMuir The actual answer worked (_and still works_) for reordering of list items when a list item is destroyed... until I discovered the (subtle) misconfiguration in setting the `:scope`.

Comment: @BrendonMuir Maybe Mark could update the answer prepending it with something such as _Although it can/should work with the ActsAsList gem core methods, ..._.

Comment: @Backo, I think the answer is a bit misleading. It might work in this scenario, but could lead to problems down the track. The real answer is to configure acts_as_list properly.